# How can I download a file with retrofit?

Tags: flutter, retrofit, dio

What ı want to achive is very simple,

I want to download a file with using retrofit package for dart and I want to show it while downloading, with progress indicator like linked tutorial but can I achive my goal using retrofit or not ?

And also, I succeed with just using dio package like tutorial but I couln't configure out adding some custom headers like x-auth or cookies without package so if you guys help me with this I will be grateful.

https://medium.com/@michallot/how-to-write-a-simple-downloading-app-with-flutter-2f55ae516867

thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hayy, if you want to add some header value to `Dio` and use it to download maybe you can configure your `Dio` like this :

```dart
Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.options.headers["x-auth"] = "your_auth_token";

// and use it like this
response = await dio.post(url, data: data);
```

And for the cookie manager capability, `Dio` offer you to use another package called name [dio_cookie_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_cookie_manager)

Thanks

Comment: thank u very much :) I will try it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i hope you can build great app with flutter